# Java 8 functional way of getting consecutive numbers of a list

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

For example I have a list of integers, as `List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)`

I want to get all of the combinations of consectuive 3 numbers in Java 8 more functional way to learn Java 8. (I know how to do it in a imperative way)

So the result for above can be a list of list as:

```
List(List(1,2,3), List(2,3,4), List(3,4,5), List(4,5,6), List(5,6,7))
```

Thanks

Comment: Can the list be random? E.g : `List(6, 7, 4, 3, 2)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it using `List.subList` while iterating over it:

```
final int subListSize = 3;
List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
List<List<Integer>> sublists = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, list.size() - subListSize)
            .mapToObj(i -> list.subList(i, i + subListSize))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it using the [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) library and its [`Seq.sliding()`](https://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/0.9.14/org/jooq/lambda/Seq.html#sliding-long-) method (`Seq` is a sequential `Stream`):

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);

List<List<Integer>> sublists = Seq.seq(list)
        .sliding(3)
        .map(Collectable::toList)
        .toList();
```

which yields:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7]]
```

Note that:

- [nullpointer's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53077069/2032415) has better performance (no new `ArrayList`s are created)
- my solution is more readable (but you can always extract [nullpointer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53077069/2032415) to a function like `List<List<T>> sublists(List<T> list, int sublistSize)`
- my solution is independent of the original `list` while [nullpointer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53077069/2032415) is a list of **[views](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-)** of original `list`

  - usually, neither original `list` nor created `sublists` are modified afterwards so it doesn't matter (and it's good for performance)
  - however, if any were to be modified, [nullpointer's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53077069/2032415) will reflect those changes (or will even break if elements are removed from the original `list`)
  - to alleviate this, add an extra `.map(List::copyOf)` after `mapToObj` in his solution (or `.map(ArrayList::new)` if you want mutable results)